# Changing the color of text in bootstrap css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my html which uses bootstrap css
I have tried with changing the color in each class but color does not change.

Which class in below code define text color? I want to make it black but it always comes with blue.

Codepan : [CODEPAN](http://codepen.io/karimkhan/pen/hxatC)

```
<div id="footer">
      <div class="container">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">     
              <li class="active"><a href="#">What is thenWat?</a></li>
              <li><a href="#about">How does it work?</a></li>
              <li><a href="#contact">Feedback</a></li>
              <li><a href="#contact">Contact us</a></li>                            
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>
```

changing

```
li
    {
        color:#000;     
    }
```

should work but no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this css

```
li, li a{ color: #000;}
```